# xCode: Retrieving images from apps documents directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, image

I've come across a problem I can't find a solution to.  I've searched the forums extensively but can't find anything. Hopefully someone might be able to shed some light.

I have an app that can save images. They are saved to the apps documents directory and the path to them is saved in a sqlite database. Every time I run/build the app, it can no longer retrieve the images that are already in the documents directory. During that same build phase I can re-save the images and then I can retrieve them just fine, but as soon as I run/build the app again it can't retrieve the images. The images are not being deleted and the path is still correct.

This is how I try retrieving them in my ViewDidLoad method

```
//database was opened. Getting path to image
NSString *logoPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 21)];
//use path to load image to a UIImage view
[self.logoView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:logoPath]];
```

I have confirmed that the image is in the documents directory still and the path is correctly assigned in my first line of code above. This code only fails when I run/build the app.  Once the app is running I can save images to the directory and retrieve them with this same code just fine, but once I run/build the app again, the images I saved on the previous build can't be pulled up even though I can see them in the directory still (I use iExplorer to view my iPhones directories).

Any ideas? Im thinking that maybe I have to initiate those images in the directory somehow in order to use them right after I build.

UPDATE - Some more info in case it will help.  After the app is built on my iPhone, I can close the app and reopen it and the images work just fine. I can even completely close the app (double click home button and end app process) and when I relaunch the app the images are retrieved from the directory just fine. But as soon as I build the app again through xCode, I cannot access the images. Something is changing when a new build is done.

UPDATE 2 - I think I found the issue and it is in the path.
This is my path

/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8A387845-7B1F-4228-9E7E-2498EC302C5A/Documents/RYal7UXrLvcompanyLogo.png

After I build the app again, this is now the new path when I save the image again

/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C0C30E2F-05D8-48F4-A0FF-603359AF5130/Documents/RYal7UXrLvcompanyLogo.png

Looks like the part in between Applications and Documents changes after every build so the path I am saving in my sqlite db is no longer valid after a new build. So now I need to figure out what that middle part is that keeps changing and how to get it after each build so I can update my paths to my images.

Comment: What you're describing should be working. There's nothing special you need to do to access existing files after you start over again. Are you sure that the `logoPath` is what you expect for the older images? What is the nature of the failure you're seeing?

Comment: Thanks Ben. I am going to look deeper into the logoPath to see if I missed something. The nature of the failure is that my logo (image) doesn't load into my UIImageView when the app is built. See the update I added to my question above.

Comment: Thanks Ben, you made me look at my paths again even though I convinced myself that they were correct. See update 2 in my question.

Comment: The changing UUID is essentially an "installation ID" and shouldn't change unless you actually delete the app off the device and then relaunch with Xcode. Is anything like that happening? Assuming not, is it somehow possible that you've got stale data in that sqlite table from previous test installations? (Also recommend verifying that the UIImage `-imageWithContentsOfFile` is returning `nil`-- presumably it is but you want to make sure you've narrowed it completely to a path issue.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the path.  Every time a new build was created, part of the path to the documents directory changed.  See UPDATE 2 in the original question above.